# how to force quit LookupViewService Processes?

Tags: activity-monitor, look-up

How do I force quit the **LookupViewService** processes?
**Activity Monitor** showed using a lot of Real Memory!

Answer (score 1):

Try running `killall LookupViewService` in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can Quit or Force Quit any process directly from Activity Monitor itself.
Select the process, click the X button, highlighted.

[image]